# Usage of relative causes (of which)

Tags: relative-clauses

Does the following sentence make sense?

> Microsoft competed in programming languages by making products of which programming languages are complementary, incompatible.

The idea I am trying to convey is:

- Programming languages are a complement of operating systems
- Microsoft wants to create their own programming language
- Microsoft made their operating systems incompatible with other programming languages

I am unsure about the ", incompatible" part of the sentence - it seems a little off.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence doesn't make sense, and i'm not sure how to convey your complex idea in a single sentence.  Perhaps this?

"Microsoft made their own operating system incompatible with other programming languages to encourage use of their own, more complementary, programming language."